# Error while starting JBoss - Could not read provided index: /content/<<warFile>>r/WEB-INF/lib/camel-api-3.0.1.jar/META-INF/jandex.idx

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, jboss-eap-7

In our project, we are using Spring Boot 2.2.4 and Apache Camel 3.0.1 and deploying the application as a war file in JBoss EAP 7.2.0. I am getting the following error while deploying the application in JBoss

```
2020-03-11 20:35:59,822 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0002: Could not read provided index: /content/<<war-file-name>>/WEB-INF/lib/camel-api-3.0.1.jar/META-INF/jandex.idx
```

Similarly I am getting error on other jandex.idx files in other locations. Can anyone please guide me what should be done here?

Comment: Camel generates its indexes with Jandex 2.1, but IIRC, EAP 7.2.x only supports Jandex 2.0. Maybe try upgrading to EAP 7.3.0 or greater and see if your app deploys.

Comment: The server up gradation will not be possible at this time. Will it be possible to skip indexing or use a lower version of Camel?

Comment: You could try with Camel 2.x.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue with JBOSS EAP 7.2.3. To quickly test a newer JBOSS EAP version I installed the current wildfly version (wildfly-20.0.1.Final). With it the problem is solved. So, updating to a JBOSS EAP 7.3.0 or newer will solve this problem.